# Object Filter for Inovice create date

Tags: date, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using rest API to get invoices whose create date is greater than some date (eg: After 1st September 2015).

```
GET
https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"createDate":{"operation":"greaterThanDate","options":[{"name":"date", "value":"10/01/2015"}]}}&resultLimit=1,5
```

but this seems to be giving first 5 invoices. May I now what is wrong in the objectFilter? Also how can I specify the date format `dd-MM-YYYY` or `mm-dd-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following REST request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey] @api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={   "invoices": {     "createDate": {       "operation": "greaterThanDate",       "options": [         {           "name": "date",           "value": [             "01/22/2016"           ]         }       ]     }   } }&objectMask=mask[createDate]
Method: GET
```

**Where:** `date format` is `mm-dd-yyyy`.

This is other example using “betweenDate”:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={   "invoices": {     "createDate": {       "operation": "betweenDate",       "options": [         {           "name": "startDate",           "value": ["02/01/2014"]         },         {           "name": "endDate",           "value": ["02/13/2014"]        }       ]     }   } }&objectMask=mask[createDate]
Method: GET
```

**References:**

[Object Filters](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)

[More SoftLayer REST API Examples](https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/More-SoftLayer-REST-API-Examples)

Comment: I would remove the references in this answer. The first one shows specifying the value as a string, and not as an array of one string. This without clarification of the difference makes looking up the reference confusing. The second points you to other examples using filters, but none of them use the date filters. You can see, however, examples of the form used in this answer on https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/getNotifications/ and https://softlayer.github.io/python/notifications/.