# Object Filter for Invoice Date not working

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to use the following REST call in Javascript to retrieve invoices for a specific date:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"isDate","options":[{"name":"date","value":["05/01/2018"]}]}}}&objectMask=mask[createDate]
```

however it always fails with error **invalid argument**.  I have even tried using the between dates answer from this previous question:

[Object Filter for Inovice create date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744591/object-filter-for-inovice-create-date)

But I still get invalid argument error.

Answer (score 0):

The error "**invalid argument**" you got is more related to the Javascript call itself.

Currently the api call you are sending and its structure is correct, although there´s an issue with the specific "isDate" operation returning empty api response, but this was  reported and other operations are working properly using filters.

Meanwhile I found a workaround, you can make use of the "betweenDate" and specify the same day, for example please see below:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["05/01/2018 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["05/01/2018 23:59:59"]}]}}}&objectMask=mask[createDate]
```

In my case I got the following response for the exact date (just as 'isDate' would work):

```
[
    {
        "createDate": "2018-05-01T02:23:56-04:00"
    },
    {
        "createDate": "2018-05-01T08:34:17-04:00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fernando.  Turns out I was not formatting my URL correctly in Javascript.  In case anyone else has the same issue, I needed to define the filter as follows:

```
var filter = JSON.stringify({"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["05/01/2018 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["05/01/2018 23:59:59"]}]}}});
```

Then my API call is this:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter=' + encodeURIComponent(filter) + '&objectMask=mask[invoiceTopLevelItems[totalRecurringAmount]]
```